# Why current_date() incurr errors in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have sql like following.

```
select *
from table
where
      c.date >= date_sub(current_date(), interval 4 day)
```

But it returned following errors

> `Syntax error at or near Line 19, Position 35`

This error was caused by `current_date()`. How can I avoid this and how can I get current date ?

If someone has opinion,please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

date_sub() function is only available in Mysql , and current_date in postgresql is not a function.

here is the correct postgresql syntax:

```
select *
from table c
where c.date >= current_date - interval '4 day';
```